# best practice for error monitoring / handling / reminder system for services in PHP

Tags: php, email, error-handling

I am using several API's and MySQL databases which sometimes throw error because of query limits or other outages!

I would love to have a solid error reminder system via e-mail which alerts me that i have to fix something, but can't trigger an e-mail each time an error occurs but only one time every hour! (i can safe the state in a file or database of course)

Anyway what's the best solution to handle this problem in php and have a clean e-mail error console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pid concept

1. when error , check is there pid file exist, like, /log/error.$app
2. if exist check the ctime
3. if ctime older than an hour or pid not exist, touch the pid, trigger email, exit
4. else return, do nothing